# Can a number consisting only of numbers $8$ and $6$ be a square of an integer?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Can a number consisting only of numbers $8$ and $6$ be a square of an integer?

I'm confused. Which approach can be used in solving this?

Comment: I think you already have the answer. $94^2$ is a close one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three digits must be divisible by 8, which means the possibilities are $888$ and $688$, as they are the only 3 digit permutations of $6,8$ that are divisible by $8$. However, a number ending in $8$ can't be a square, so this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Can a number ending in $8$ be a square?  If a number ends in $6$ and has an even tens digit, how many times does $2$ divide into it?